# Topics for the Skeptics podcast

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, podcast

Hello fellow Skeptics!

As you know, [Larian](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/386/larian-lequella) and I have been recording a [podcast](/questions/tagged/podcast) for a few months now. It's a lot of fun for us, but we want to make it more useful for the community.

What topics should we talk about? This should be a tag (or even a more general topic).

Please put one topic each answer in this format, and then vote!

```
[tag:<topicname>]

## Blurb

<topicname> is a fantastic topic because it has the best questions. 
Our questions are incredible, everybody says so.

## Questions

* https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/123
* https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/124
* https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/125
```

Answer (score 3):

[natural-remedies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-remedies)

### Blurb

Natural remedies are "natural" solutions to common problems such as healthcare conditions, but also everyday nuisances and problems. We have more than 100 questions about this very common topic, full of misconceptions!

### Questions

- [Is squeezing pimples bad for you?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/is-squeezing-pimples-bad-for-you)
- [Does aloe vera help cure sunburn?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10005/does-aloe-vera-help-cure-sunburn)
- [Can I get high using binaural beats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/can-i-get-high-using-binaural-beats)

Comment: Should "[tag:homeopathy]" get bundled in?

Answer (score 1):

[aviation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation)

### Blurb

Selfishly, I'm a total aviation geek and just like reading/hearing about things to do with that subject. Less selfishly we have a great range of questions from  supposed conspiracies to airplanes flying with only 1 wing. There's plenty to talk about.

### Questions

- [Did a plane hit the Pentagon on September 11, 2001?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6187/did-a-plane-hit-the-pentagon-on-september-11-2001)
- [Is this picture of a bent propeller genuine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32633/is-this-picture-of-a-bent-propeller-genuine)
- [Can aircraft be hacked and "commandeered remotely"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31976/can-aircraft-be-hacked-and-commandeered-remotely)
- [Was MH17 shot down?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22437/was-mh17-shot-down)
- [Are personal electronics a risk to commercial aviation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/are-personal-electronics-a-risk-to-commercial-aviation)
- [Did an F-15 airplane successfully land with just one wing?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/did-an-f-15-airplane-successfully-land-with-just-one-wing)